# I'm not able to deploy Strapi backend on Render

Tags: sqlite, strapi

I getting this error often and i'm not moving further from this :-

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x49Y.png)

Here my .env file for backend file

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBZNq.png)

If anybody have any idea please help me what this problem says i don't understand and help me to solve this problem